# Pine script - How to use two exit conditions on one position ID?

Tags: pine-script

Once a position is long or short I have three exit conditions
1)ATR based stop is hit
2)Close position if close price moves to the wrong side of the EMA value
3)Once moving averages flip the open trade closes then opens in the other direction

1 and 3 work fine. I'm having trouble with 2) close when price moves above/below EMA and am not receiving an error code.

Here is the script:

```
//@version=4
//Strategy 

//Inputs

startTime = input(title="Start Time", type = input.time, defval = timestamp("01 Jan 2017 00:00 +0000"))
endTime = input(title="End Time", type = input.time, defval = timestamp("01 Jan 2023 00:00 +0000"))

//Time
inDateRange = (time >= startTime) and (time < endTime)

fastSMALen = input(title="Fast SMA Length", type=input.integer, defval=9)
slowSMALen = input(title="Slow SMA Length", type=input.integer, defval=21)
exitEMALen = input(title="Exit EMA", type=input.integer, defval=20)

//Stop Loss inputs
atrLen = input(title="ATR Length", type=input.integer, defval=10)
stopOffset = input(title="Stop ATR Multiple", type=input.float,
     defval=2, minval=0.01)

//Position Sizing inputs
PosSizeLoss = input(title="Risk $", type=input.integer, 
     defval=200) //Amount to risk losing on a trade
    
//Calculate strategy values

fastSMA = sma(close, fastSMALen)
slowSMA = sma(close, slowSMALen)
**exitEMA = ema(close, exitEMALen)**

atrValue = atr(atrLen)

//Calculate Posotion Size
PosSizeUnits = PosSizeLoss/(atrValue*stopOffset)

//Trading conditions
long = crossover(fastSMA, slowSMA) and inDateRange
short = crossunder(fastSMA, slowSMA) and inDateRange
**lema_exit = crossover(close, exitEMA) and inDateRange**
**sema_exit = crossover(close, exitEMA) and inDateRange**


//Command to execute long trades - strateg.long says buy long, 
if (long)
    stopLoss = low - atrValue*stopOffset
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, PosSizeUnits) //stop=high for the day the indicators crosses using stop order
    strategy.exit("exit", "long", stop=stopLoss) 
    strategy.close("long", when = lema_exit)
   
    
//Command to execute short trades 
if (short)
    stopLoss = high + atrValue*stopOffset
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, PosSizeUnits) // stop = low for the day the indicator crosses
    strategy.exit("exit", "short", stop=stopLoss)
    strategy.close("short", sema_exit)
    
//Command to close all trades outside of timeframe
if (not inDateRange)
    strategy.close_all()
```

I've tried two exit.strategy and this isn't possible because you cant have two exit conditions for one position ID, however I can see on the charts that the script above isn't exiting when there is a close on the other side of my exitEMA.

I also tried `when = cross(close, exitEMA)` but its the same outcome.

Any ideas much appreciated, is strategy.close and strategy.exit conflicting without throwing an error somehow?

Comment: The possible reason is `strategy.close` calls in your script executes when entry conditions occurs only. Try to move out it from `if (long)` and `if (short)` scopes.

Comment: Thanks @AndreyD, I can confirm that worked. Thanks very much for the help!